# Adjust Price Display for Variable Product in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I want to adjust the price display for a variable product so that instead displaying as something like "$10.00-$12.00" it will display as "$10.00 or $12.00" -- essentially replacing the ndash with an "or".

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into `woocommerce_variable_price_html` and reformat the price to include or.  This will replace the `&ndash;` with `or` on all products with multiple differing prices.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price_seperator', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price_seperator( $price, $product ) {

    $price = '';
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
    $max_price = end( $prices['price'] );

    if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) {
            $price = $min_price !== $max_price ? sprintf( _x( '%1$s <span class="or">or</span> %2$s', 'Price range: from-to', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ), wc_price( $max_price ) ) : wc_price( $min_price );

    }

    return $price;
}
```